# Using lasso regression in Matlab with constraints on lambda values

Tags: regression, matlab, lasso, parameterization, constraint

I have successfully ran a lasso regression on Matlab, however, some of the lambda values result in a non-steady state solutions for my linear problem. I would like to basically force the regression to give me lambda values that would give me stable solutions, and to do that I need the fitted coefficients as organized in 'B' to be all negative. Is there anyway I can apply this sort of constraint within the regression?

Comment: What do stable/steady state solutions mean and how do they relate to lambda (presumably the regularization parameter) and negative coefficients?

Comment: I should have made it more clear, @user20160. So the steady state solutions tell me if how stable my lotka-volterra model is. And the model incorporates the regularization parameters as interaction species between competing species in my model. It turns out, when the coefficients a positive coefficient, it gives me a negative steady solution when my model is at equilibrium and that's not a real solution in terms of what I'm looking for. SO, I want to make the lasso regression give me only positive lambda values by adding a constraint.

Comment: Marko, if you are the same as `Mark`, then please visit http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts.  That will enable you to comment on and edit your post.

Comment: Still a bit confused. Is lambda your regularization parameter, and how are you fitting it? I haven't ever heard of this being negative, which would encourage the weights to be large and non-sparse (opposite the usual purpose of lasso). If you want to constrain the weights to be negative, there's something called the 'nonnegative lasso', which you might be able to modify to give nonpositive weights instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Matlab, but using glmnet within R, you can fit lasso penalized models (set the mixing parameter `alpha=1`), and can bound the coefficients using the `lower.limit` and/or `upper.limit` commands (the default is no bound).